# Should i use property or Dictionary object for cashing config data

Tags: c#

I am caching my applications Web.config Key-Value data to a Singleton object where i can store config data in class properties or a dictionary object. Considering performance and flexibility i am not able to decide between using dictionary or class properties.

1. dictionary offers less changes whenever a new Key is added/removed as i don't have to make any modifications to my Singleton model logic whereas if i use properties i need to manage additions/removal of respective Key.
2. While using dictionary i need to specify key name in string which is error prone and difficult to manage.

Based on above two reasons currently i am using dictionary for storing cached data. Please suggest if any better solution exists Here is my Sample Code.

```
public class ConfigData
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The configuration data
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly IDictionary<string, string> ConfigurationData = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes the <see cref="ConfigData" /> class.
    /// </summary>
    static ConfigData()
    {
        try
        {
            ConfigurationData = NVCExtender.ToDictionary(ConfigurationManager.GetSection("appSettings") as NameValueCollection);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What if you don't cache? I mean directly access `config` data through `ConfigurationManager`. Is there any problem with this?

Comment: The reason behind cashing web config data was my myth that if we cash it then we don't require to parse config XML add read required key-value by making use of ConfigurationManager class. But class ConfigurationManager exactly does what I wanted to achieve by cashing XML key-value data.

Comment: There is a reason why these options are in xml file, if you want to change any values, you need to handle when to refresh that cache for new values. It's better not to cache as I see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ConfigurationManager.AppSettings` is already a `NameValueCollection` and there is little value in replacing this with your own `Dictionary<string,string>`.

Representing appSettings as properties of a static or singleton class has a number of benefits:

- You can have validation and null checking in one place.
- You can make your properties strongly-typed
- You can provide default values for missing appSettings in one place.
- You get intellisense when accessing the setting.

All design is trade-off, so whether or not these benefits justify the effort of writing and maintaining the static/singleton class is a judgement call.  I often have an internal static class in each Assembly that uses more than one or two appSettings, with a strongly-typed property for each appSetting used by that Assembly.

If you do this, it's worth adopting a naming convention so that it's clear which appSettings belong to which assemblies, for example "MyAssembly1.MySetting", "MyAssembly2.MyOtherSetting".

Answer (score 2):

You can create a class that wraps the `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings` or an `IDictionary<string, string>` and exposes properties that read/update the underlying object as the following:

For `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings`, you can do the following:

```
public class ConfigManager
{
    public string IPAddress
    {
         get
         {
             if (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Keys.Any(k => k == "IPAddr"))
                 return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.GetValues("IPAddr")[0];

             return null;
         }
         set
         {
             if (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Keys.Any(k => k == "IPAddr"))
                 ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Remove("IPAddr");

             ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Add("IPAddr", value);
         } 
    }
```

For `IDictionary<string, string>`, you can do the following:

```
public class ConfigManager
{
    private readonly IDictionary<string, string> m_Dictionary;

    public ConfigManager(IDictionary<string, string> dictionary)
    {
        m_Dictionary = dictionary;
    }

    public string IPAddress
    {
         get
         {
             if (m_Dictionary.ContainsKey("IPAddr"))
                return m_Dictionary["IPAddr"];

             return null;
         }
         set
         {
             if (m_Dictionary.ContainsKey("IPAddr"))
                 m_Dictionary.Remove("IPAddr");

             m_Dictionary.Add("IPAddr", value);
         } 
    }
```